# Request.URL for localhost and live site

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, request

I have my local host and a live site. I have a url and if its in localhost the url should go localhost/site/thank_you.aspx and if its live http://mylivesite.com/thank_you.aspx

I have tried this in my code behind...

```
MyHiddenField.Value = Request.URL + "/thank_you.aspx";
```

but it returned the page I was on /thank_you.aspx

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not use a relative path: `MyHiddenField.Value = "/thank_you.aspx";`?

Comment: @Alex Maybe it's being used to create a link for an email, etc.

Comment: Do you mean that `http://localhost/something` should "go to" `http://localhost/site/thank_you.aspx` but that `http://mylivesite.com/something` should go to `http://mylivesite.com/thank_you.aspx`? Where is your web site on `localhost`?

Answer (score 8):

Try this, I even added scheme in too, just in case you go https :)

**EDIT: Also added port (Thanks Alex)** in order to be **super duper super future-proof :)**

```
MyHiddenField.Value = string.Format(
    "{0}://{1}{2}/thank_you.aspx",  
    Request.Url.Scheme, 
    Request.Url.Host,
    Request.Url.IsDefaultPort ? string.Empty : ":" + Request.Url.Port);
```

**EDIT: Another good suggestion by @MikeSmithDev, put it in a function**

```
public string GetUrlForPage(string page)
{
    return MyHiddenField.Value = string.Format(
       "{0}://{1}{2}/{3}",  
        Request.Url.Scheme, 
        Request.Url.Host,
        Request.Url.IsDefaultPort ? string.Empty : ":" + Request.Url.Port,
        page);
}
```

Then you can do:

```
MyHiddenField.Value = GetUrlForPage("thank_you.aspx");
```

Comment: You're welcome :) Also, one should watch out for the port number if it's not 80 in some deployment scenario.

Comment: +1 for the https option. Another good consideration for OP is to make this a global function that he could call like `MakeURL("/thank_you.aspx")`

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Added a function option now too :)

Comment: @mattytommo I like it. I have something similar in my site that I put together about 3-4 years ago that accounts for https and port... but this is better. I may steal it and not give you credit :) Another fool-proof option is to trim the "/" from the beginning of the `string page` if the coder uses function wrong ;)

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Haha feel free! :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a built-in class `UriBuilder`

```
var url = Request.Url;
var newurl = new UriBuilder(url.Scheme, url.Host, url.Port, "thank_you.aspx")
                 .ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answers above. Allow function to handle relative paths. For example: ~/ or ~/test/default.aspx

```
public string GetUrlForPage(string relativeUrl)
{
    return string.Format(
       "{0}://{1}{2}{3}",
        Request.Url.Scheme,
        Request.Url.Host,
        Request.Url.IsDefaultPort ? string.Empty : ":" + Request.Url.Port,
        Page.ResolveUrl(relativeUrl));
}
```